# How to paste to the beginning of a line?

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out how to `paste some texts I yanked` to the beginning of another line.

Methods I tried, but not actually correct:
==> After I put my cursor to the 1st letter of a line, 
(1) I did p to paste. But the copied texts are pasted 1 char behind the 1st char of that line.
(2) I also tried v^p, but got the same result.

Any better ways to do it?

Comment: Press P to paste before the cursor, or p to paste after

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Yank your text.
- Go to the desired line, jump to the beginning by pressing zero `0`.
- Instead of pressing `p` to paste, press `Shift p`